# Is it possible to send Calendar invite in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to send a calendar invite through Windows Phone 7 programatically. I currently am able to open the email composer with some default text. But I need to include a schedule in it so that it goes as a calendar invite as opposed to a plain text email.

```
EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
email.Subject = "Invitation for an envent";
email.Body = "Attend this event on June 21 2012";
email.Show();
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do this is not available with the framework as it is today.

If you need to send appointments/invites via email you'll need to send these from an external source (which you could, of course, trigger from your app).

Comment: +1.. thanks for the answer.. is it possible to send an invite through attachment ?

Comment: Attachments are not supported through the out-of-the-box Windows Phone APIs.

Comment: Also, calendar access from the API is in read-only mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx